# MySql query to get count of days spent in each country for each purpose? (Get count of all record in second table present in first table)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables tl_log, tl_geo_countries,tl_purpose. I am trying to get the count of number of days spent in each country in table 'tl_log' for each purpose in table 'tl_purpose'. 
I tried below mysql query

```
SELECT t.country_id AS countryID,t.reason_id AS reasonID,count(t.reason_id) AS 
days,c.name AS country, p.purpose AS purpose
FROM `tl_log` AS t
LEFT JOIN tl_geo_countries AS c ON t.country_id=c.id
LEFT JOIN tl_purpose AS p ON t.reason_id=p.id
GROUP BY t.reason_id,t.country_id ORDER BY days DESC
```

But landed up with.

[image]

I am not able to get the count for purpose for each country in 'tl_log' that is not present in table 'tl_log'. Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, Please let me know if the question is difficult to understand.

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Below is the structure of these three tables

**tl_log**

[image: tl_log]

**tl_geo_countries**

[image: tl_geo_countries]

**tl_purpose**

[image: tl_purpose]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all possible combination of countries and purposes, even those that do not appear on the log table (these will be shown with a count of 0), you can do first a cartesian product of the two tables (a `CROSS` join) and then `LEFT` join to the log table:

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS countryID,
    p.id AS reasonID,
    COUNT(t.reason_id) AS days,
    c.name AS country, 
    p.purpose AS purpose
FROM 
    tl_geo_countries AS c 
  CROSS JOIN
    tl_purpose AS p 
  LEFT JOIN
    tl_log AS t
      ON  t.country_id = c.id
      AND t.reason_id = p.id
GROUP BY 
    p.id,
    c.id 
ORDER BY 
    days DESC ;
```

If you want the records for only the countries that are present in the log table (but still all possible reason/purposes), a slight modification is needed:

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS countryID,
    p.id AS reasonID,
    COUNT(t.reason_id) AS days,
    c.name AS country, 
    p.purpose AS purpose
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
          country_id
      FROM 
          tl_log 
    ) AS dc  
  JOIN
    tl_geo_countries AS c
      ON c.id = dc.country_id
  CROSS JOIN
    tl_purpose AS p 
  LEFT JOIN
    tl_log AS t
      ON  t.country_id = c.id
      AND t.reason_id = p.id
GROUP BY 
    p.id,
    c.id 
ORDER BY 
    days DESC ;
```

Comment: unexpected result.  I want the records for only the countries that are present in tl_log

Comment: I think the second query works. I am still testing it. I will mark the solution as accepted once I am done. Thank you so much for you great help.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` should be replaced by `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: Can you post a copy of expected output for better understanding

Comment: Here is my RIGHT JOIN "SELECT t.country_id AS countryID,count(t.reason_id) AS days,c.name AS country, p.purpose AS purpose 
FROM `tl_travel_log` AS t 
LEFT JOIN tl_geo_countries AS c ON t.country_id=c.id
RIGHT JOIN tl_purpose AS p ON t.reason_id=p.id
GROUP BY t.reason_id,t.country_id ORDER BY days DESC" and got the output as http://i46.tinypic.com/21oq5v.png

Comment: just few mins I will post the image of expected output

Comment: Please see the Expected Output in the question which I added just now.

Comment: If a country is not present in the TL_LOG table do you also want it to appear in the output?

Comment: @AndyMc no. I want the records for only the country that is present in tl_log